# Getting started with SharePoint 2010 for SharePoint 2007 Developers

Tags: 2007, learning, development

Do you know some quick links that will help a SharePoint 2007 Developers to get started with SharePoint 2010.

Let me start with the links I know.

1. [General Information on SharePoint 2010](http://blog.ksenthil.net/archive/2009/11/06/sharepoint-2010-ndash-resources.aspx)
2. [Must watch videos for SharePoint 2010](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/SharePoint2010Developer/)

Comment: Made community wiki. See why here: http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/432/what-does-community-wiki-mean

Comment: Thanks Alex! I in fact wanted to change at a later stage.

Answer (score 2):

The MSDN SharePoint 2010 Developer Center should be one resource to start with:

[SharePoint 2010 (beta) on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee514561.aspx)

Or discuss it (if you don't do it here):

[MSDN Discussions on SharePoint 2010](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/sharepoint2010,sharepoint)

Answer (score 2):

Channel 9 has a series of videos for learning SharePoint 2010.

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/VisualStudio/Sharepoint-Development-with-Visual-Studio-2010/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like effort is already put into the 2010 SDK:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/ee557253%28en-us,office.14%29.aspx

Now **thats** a first! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some good links:

SharePoint 2010 Developer and IT Pro learning guide: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ac9a3851-c298-4f4f-b7f0-63d756d2bde9&displaylang=en

Getting Started developing on SharePoint 2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513147.aspx

Videos from SharePoint conference 2009: http://www.mssharepointconference.com/pages/videohighlights.aspx

SharePoint 2010 End user training: http://www.point8020.com/SharePointEndUserTraining.aspx

SharePoint 2010 Site: http://sharepoint2010.microsoft.com/Pages/default.aspx

SharePoint 2010 Developer Center: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee514561.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've found this to be really helpful - the 'SharePoint 2010 Beta Developer Training Kit'

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bfd1603b-7550-4b8e-be85-4215a5069b90&displaylang=en

It comes with few linked html pages which provide the links to the videos and exercises.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some good training material offered [here](http://www.learndevnow.com/Default.aspx?src=EB1062D) at LearnDevNow

P.S. I don't work for them but we're beginning to use their material as they have a good offer: $99 for the package that usually cost $349

Answer (score 0):

I have written a range of blog posts about [moving a WSPBuilder solution from SharePoint 2007 to 2010](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2010/03/porting-sharepoint-2007-wspbuilder.html).

Quite insightful if you have experience with SharePoint 2007 development.