# Customization best practices for SP2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, css, best-practices

We'd like to customize the look of our SharePoint 2010 pages and sites but didn't know what some best practices are:

- We'd like to change the look of pages some without breaking the link between them and their master pages. In other words, if you change a page in Designer, it won't take the changes from the master page later.
- Also, we'd like to create our own CSS styles and modify existing styles. What's the best way to do this? Should we use our own CSS file?
- Will these changes cause problems if we later need to upgrade to a newer version of SharePoint?

Thank you and sorry if these are newbie questions :)

Comment: This is a near duplicate of '[How to deal with SharePoint design complexity and web designer creativity?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10128/how-to-deal-with-sharepoint-design-complexity-and-web-designer-creativity/10130#10130)', which has some great answers as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The phrase you're looking for is "SharePoint Branding"

Perhaps the best place is to start is [Heather Solomons blog](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/brandsppart1.aspx)

Other links that may help

- [SharePoint Magazine - Branding Limitations](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/sharepoints-branding-limitations-part-1)
- [MSDN - Real World Branding with SharePoint 2010 Publishing Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430141.aspx)
- [Codeplex - SharePoint Branding Tool](http://brandingtool.codeplex.com/)
- [Tom Wilsons SharePoint Branding Blog](http://styledpoint.com/blog/)
- [Randy Drisgill - SharePoint Branding and Design](http://blog.drisgill.com/)

Comment: Heather's blog is great for branding SharePoint 2007 but many of the key aspects for branding have changed in 2010 so it really would be best for Alex to focus specifically on branding in 2010.

Answer (score 6):

you could try my free SharePoint MasterPages too
http://freespmp.codeplex.com and I have some info on my blog http://engageinsharepoint.co.uk

Thanks

Matthew Hughes - @mattoo2

Answer (score 6):

Matt and Randys' Master Pages make branding from scratch really easy. If you need hep with basic Themes rather than branding (or to save hours of work) use Microsoft's Theme Builder - I wrote a post on what everything relates to [here](http://www.sharepointdesigner.co.za/2011/08/02/microsoft-theme-builder-what-does-everything-do/):  -> Theme-ing really does help you save some time on the base CSS.

Comment: Thanks, Louise. That's a very useful article. Awhile back, we tried using Theme Builder but couldn't figure it out. This article's the ticket :)

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance :) If you need help just let me know, I do themes for the community to help out :)